# Minecraft PE nether portal

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I built the portal 4x5, so why won't it light. I'm playing single player with all setting on. What did I do wrong

Comment: Did you just build the obisidian structure, or did you try to light it with a flint&stone?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a picture so that we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Please post a screenshot so we can understand your issue better. There are a few possibilities, mentioned by Sum1.

1. You are not lighting the portal with flint and steel.
2. You are leaving a gap in the portal or have an extra misplaced block. Crying Obsidian will not work for nether portals.
3. The Nether is disabled in your world.
4. There is a flowing liquid obstructing it.
5. I believe in older Minecraft versions (I'm going off my Console experience), you could not make a Nether portal that strayed from the standard.

In general, we'll be able to assist better if you give us what version you are on, and show us a screenshot.

Comment: Make sure you do not have any crying obsidian inside of the portal. It does not work with crying obsidian.

Comment: People only play latest versions in bedrock

Comment: @Penguin I wasn't sure if people could go to older Bedrock versions, hence why I listed that anyway just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I should also add that Nether portals do not function in the "Old"(Limited sized) World setting on Bedrock Edition.

If you're on the "Infinite"/default or "Flat" world types, then this restriction doesn't apply, and Nether portals should be able to function normally.